# How can i write a mocha test for the following function?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I want to write a test for this node.js funcion,This has two arguments request and response. I set the request variable . But dont know how to set response variable.

```
 function addCustomerData(request, response) {
                common.getCustomerByMobile(request.param('mobile_phone'), function (customerdata) {
                    if (!customerdata) {
                        var areaInterest = request.param('area_interest');
                        var customerInfo = {userType: request.param('userType'),
                            firstName   : request.param('first_name'),
                            middleName  : request.param('middle_name'),
                            lastName    : request.param('last_name'),
                            email       : request.param('email'),
                            mobilePhone : request.param('mobile_phone'),
                            uniqueName  : request.param('user_name'),
                            company     : request.param('company')
                        };
                        if(customerInfo.email){
                            customerInfo.email = customerInfo.email.toLowerCase();
                        }
                        if(customerInfo.uniqueName){
                            customerInfo.uniqueName = customerInfo.uniqueName.toLowerCase();
                        }
                        if(areaInterest) {
                            customerInfo.areaInterest = '{' + areaInterest + '}';
                        }else
                            areaInterest = null;
                        addCustomer(request, response, customerInfo, function (data) {
                                request.session.userId = data;
                                return response.send({success: true, message: 'Inserted successfully'});
                            }
                        );
                    } else {
                        return response.send({success: false, message: 'User with this mobile number already exists'});
                    }
                });
    }
```

I wrote the test as follows

```
describe('signup', function(){
    describe('#addCustomer()', function(){
        before(function (done) {
            request = {};
            request.data = {};
            request.session = {};
            request.data['userType'] = '3';
            request.data['first_name'] = 'Shiji';
            request.data['middle_name'] = '';
            request.data['last_name'] = 'George';
            request.data['email'] = 'shiji@lastplot.com';
            request.data['mobile_phone'] = '5544332333';
            request.data['user_name'] = 'shiji';
            request.session['imageArray'] = [];
            request.param=function(key){
                // Look up key in data
                return this.data[key];
            };
            request1 = {};
            request1.data = {};
            request1.session = {};
            request1.data['area_interest']=["aluva","ernakulam"];
            request1.data['userType'] = '1';
            request1.data['first_name'] = 'Hari';
            request1.data['middle_name'] = 'G';
            request1.data['last_name'] = 'Ganesh';
            request1.data['email'] = 'hari@lastplot.com';
            request1.data['mobile_phone'] = '5544332321';
            request1.data['user_name'] = 'hariganesh';
            request1.data['company'] = 'HG Realestate';
            request1.session['imageArray'] = [];
            request1.param=function(key){
                // Look up key in data
                return this.data[key];
            };
  done();
        });
        it('It should list the matching properties', function(done){

            async.parallel([
                function(callback) {
                    signup.addCustomerData(request, response, function (result, err) {
                        should.not.exist(err);
                        should.exists(result);
                        callback();
                    });
                },
                function(callback) {
                    signup.addCustomerData(request1, response, function (result, err) {
                        should.not.exist(err);
                        should.exists(result);
                        callback();
                    });
                }],function(){
                done();
            });
        });
```

But i got the error as *response* has no method *send()*

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Your addCustomerData function does not have a callback, it just calls respond.send(). You need to mock the response object, as well as the send method, and put your tests inside of it, but you won't be able to use async.parallel() as, like I already mentioned, your function does not have a callback parameter. If you're testing request/response functions, I suggest you look into Supertest https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest which is widely used for cases like this.